# Firestore maximum nested depth

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

What is the maximum nest depth in Google Firebase's new Firestore?

The real time database's limit is 32:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data

If you need more depth, is it better to just flatten the key paths into a string, as some NoSQL databases do (E.g Elastic search)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximum depth of subcollections is `100`.

And Maximum size for a document is `1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)`

You can find all limits and quotas [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)